# formatting each statement results inside a grid?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have fetched and parsed some data and I am using 'each' to display it:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&output=rss'),
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function (data) {
        if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
            $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
                $('.row').append("<div class=\"threecol\"">title: " + e.title + "<br></div>");
            });
        } 
    }
});
```

And for the grid to function properly it needs to follow this structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="threecol">
        </div>
        <div class="threecol">
        </div>
        <div class="threecol">
        </div>
        <div class="threecol last">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So my question is, how would I sort through the each statement and place every 4 items into a new row and make every 4th item have the class "threecol last" instead of "threecol"?**

Comment: with a counter and an if - else structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a counter before your `$.each` loop, and then add some simple conditions to insert the `rows` at the correct position, and assign the correct classes:

```
if (c % 4 == 0) { 
  $('<div />').addClass('row').appendTo('.container'); 
}

$('<div />').addClass('threecol')
            .text('title: ' + e.title)
            .appendTo('.row:last');

if (c % 4 == 3) {
  $('.threecol:last').addClass('last');
}

c++;
```

Comment: I believe that, for functions inside an each loop in jQuery, passing the argument `i` gives the index of the selection within the jQuery array, so you can do away with an external counter.

Comment: @ckersch it does give the index, but it's not always a sequential numeric value

Comment: @billyonecan It's always a sequential numeric value if the data is an array - from jquery source: for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
 value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ); the second argument to call is the first argument to your callback. +1 for use of mod operator.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Thanks :) It's not always an array, though. In the question above the response is a json encoded object. I'm gonna hang my neck out here and say that, in this instance, the indices are **not** sequential numeric values

Comment: Yes only @BenSmith can answer that. Is entries an array or an object, Ben?